# movsx in python

Tags: python, assembly, signed

I am trying to decompile asm code to python. I encountered the following line

```
movsx eax, byte ptr [edi]
```

I am looking for a way to do signed extension of a byte in python. I am currently using bytearray to get the individual bytes. After getting the individual bytes I need to do a signed extension for each of them.

Comment: I think there is a bit of information missing.  Python doesn't have sized integer data types, so you don't need "signed extension".  If you are using something like the `array` module for arrays that do have sizef integer values, the signed extension will happen autmatically when necessaty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following snippet:

```py
# sign extend b low bits in x
# from "Bit Twiddling Hacks"
def SIGNEXT(x, b):
  m = 1 << (b - 1)
  x = x & ((1 << b) - 1)
  return (x ^ m) - m
```

In your case b will be 8. You can probably precalculate the masks for a bit of speedup.

The referenced hack can be found [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).